# Select distinct records on a join

Tags: mysql, select, join, distinct

I have two mysql tables - a sales table:

```
+----------------+------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type                         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| StoreId        | bigint(20) unsigned          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| ItemId         | bigint(20) unsigned          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| SaleWeek       | int(10) unsigned             | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+----------------+------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and an items table:

```
+--------------------+------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type                         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ItemId             | bigint(20) unsigned          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| ItemName           | varchar(100)                 | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The sales table contains multiple records for each **ItemID** - one for each **SaleWeek**.  I want to select all items sold by joining the two tables like so:

```
SELECT items.ItemName, items.ItemId FROM items
JOIN sales ON items.ItemId = sales.ItemId 
WHERE sales.StoreID = ? ORDER BY sales.SaleWeek DESC;
```

However, this is returning multiple **ItemId** values based on the multiple entries for each **SaleWeek**.  Can I do a distinct select to only return one **ItemID** - I don't want to have to query for the latest **SaleWeek** because some items may not have an entry for the latest **SaleWeek** so I need to get the last sale.  Do I need to specify **DISTINCT** or use a **LEFT OUTER JOIN** or something?

Comment: Have you tried DISTINCT?  It may screw up your ordering, depending on what DBMS you use...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A `DISTINCT` should do what you're looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT items.ItemName, items.ItemId FROM items
JOIN sales ON items.ItemId = sales.ItemId 
WHERE sales.StoreID = ? ORDER BY sales.SaleWeek DESC;
```

That would return only distinct `items.ItemName, items.ItemId` tuples.

Answer (score 12):

You had comment about the sales week too.  And wanting the most recent week, you may want to try using a GROUP BY

```
SELECT 
      items.ItemName, 
      items.ItemId,
      max( Sales.SaleWeek ) MostRecentSaleWeek
   FROM 
      items JOIN sales ON items.ItemId = sales.ItemId
   WHERE 
      sales.StoreID = ? 
   GROUP BY
      items.ItemID,
      items.ItemName
   ORDER BY
      MostRecentSaleWeek,   -- ordinal column number 3 via the MAX() call
      items.ItemName
```

You may have to change the ORDER BY to the ordinal 3rd column reference if you so want based on that column..  This query will give you each distinct item AND the most recent week it was sold.

Answer (score 2):

```
    SELECT  u.user_name,u.user_id, u.user_country,u.user_phone_no,ind.Industry_name,inv.id,u.user_email
    FROM invitations inv
    LEFT JOIN users u
    ON inv.sender_id = u.user_id
    LEFT JOIN employee_info ei
    ON inv.sender_id=ei.employee_fb_id   
    LEFT JOIN industries ind
    ON ei.industry_id=ind.id
    WHERE inv.receiver_id='XXX'
    AND inv.invitation_status='0'
    AND inv.invitati

on_status_desc='PENDING'
GROUP BY (user_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use this:

```
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `name`) SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.`employee_id`,b.`first_name` FROM `employee_leave_details`as a INNER JOIN 
    `employee_register` as b ON a.`employee_id` = b.`employee_id`
```