# How to make an inner join while maintaining unique rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb

I have a ternary relationship in which I stablish the relation between Offers, Profiles, and Skills. The ternary relationship table, called `ternary` for example, has the IDs of the three tables as primary key. It could look something like this:

```
id_Offer    -   id_Profile  -   id_Skill
1           -   1           -   1
1           -   1           -   2
1           -   1           -   3
1           -   2           -   1
2           -   1           -   1
2           -   3           -   2
2           -   1           -   3
2           -   5           -   1
[and so on, there would be more registers for each id_Offer from Offer but I want to limit the example]
```

So I have 2 offers in total, with a number of profiles in each one.

The table Offer looks something like this:

```
Offer   -   business_name
1       -   business-1
2       -   business-1
3       -   business-1
4       -   business-1
5       -   business-2 
6       -   business-2 
7       -   business-2 
8       -   business-3
```

So when I do a query like

```
select distinct id_offer, business_name, COUNT(*)
FROM Offer
GROUP BY business_name
Order by COUNT(*);
```

I get that for business-1 I have 4 offers.

Now if I want to take into account the offers for some Profile, I have to make a join with my ternary relationship. But even if I do something as simple as the following

```
select distinct business_name
from Offer
INNER JOIN  ternary ON Offer.id_Offer = ternary.id_Offer
GROUP BY business_name
WHERE business_name =  'business-1'
```

No matter what I put on the group by, or if I write distinct or not, I do not get what I want. The reality is that for business-1, I have 4 offers. Right now in the ternary only appear two. So it should return 2 unique offers for this name with no filtering by profile.

But instead I get 8 offers, because that is how many times it appears in the ternary, the id_Offer's that match.

How should this be done? If I need no filters I can simply look at Offers table alone. But what if I need to filter by id_skill or id_Profile AND want to return the business_name?

I have seen solutions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068566/6028947) but I can not make them work, I do not understand what the  `?` is, how is it called to learn more about it, if MariaDB works the same in this sense, I could not find information about it because I do not know how that operation is called. When I try to build that query for my data I get:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC' at line 1
```

But as I said, it is kind of hard to look for '?' as an... Operator? Function?

Comment: The sample data columns don't match the query columns.

Comment: You rarely never combine GROUP BY with SELECT DISTINCT, because GROUP BY eliminates duplicates.

Comment: Further, you will never need to  use a GROUP BY clause in the absence of any aggregating functions.

Comment: @jarlh rarely or never - which?

Comment: @Strawberry, can be combined once in while, but very rarely.

Comment: @jarlh Ah, 'rarely, if ever,'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic solutions.

```
SELECT
  o.business_name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT o.id_offer)   AS unique_offers
FROM
  Offer     AS o
INNER JOIN
  ternary   AS t
    ON t.id_Offer = o.id_Offer
WHERE
      o.business_name = 'business-1'
  AND t.id_profile IN (1, 2, 3, 5)
GROUP BY
  o.business_name
```

That's the simplest to write and think about.  But, it can also be quite intensive because you're still joining each row in `offer` to 4 rows in `ternary` - Creating 8 rows to aggregate and process through `DISTINCT`.

The "better" *(in my opinion)* route is to filter then aggregate the `ternary` table in a sub-query.

```
SELECT
  o.business_name,
  COUNT(*)         AS unique_offers
FROM
  Offer     AS o
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT id_Offer
    FROM ternary
   WHERE id_profile IN (1, 2, 3, 5)
GROUP BY id_Offer
)
  AS t
    ON t.id_Offer = o.id_Offer
WHERE
  o.business_name = 'business-1'
GROUP BY
  o.business_name
```

This ensures the `t` only ever has one row for any given offer.  This in turn means that each row in `offer` only ever joins to one row in `t`; no duplication.  That in turn means there is no need to use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` and relieves some overhead *(By moving it to the inner query's `GROUP BY`)*.

Comment: If I remove the filter from profile I get the number I am supposed to get. That's great!! Now I have a question, and this probably has to do with my data but... Why if I filter by each profile, one by one, the sum of the COUNT is bigger than when I do not filter by profile in the subquery and only filter by business_name (meaning: Suppose I want offers from ALL profiles. If I remove the filter of profile that's what I should get right? But the numbers do not match).

Comment: @monkeyintern - Because `id_offer == 1` is included in profiles 1 and 2.  And `id_offer == 2` is included in profiles 1 and 3 and 5.  So, no, they shouldn't add up...  `Offers_For_Profile_1` *(2)* + `Offers_For_Profile_2` *(1)* will be ***higher*** than `Offers_For_Profile_1_Or_2` *(2)*...

Comment: How would you go about doing this same thing but with outter joins added to the mix? I am failing to apply the right syntax. The idea is to do the same, filter then aggregate, but once it is filtered, outside of that, I make several joins. How should I label tables in that case?

Comment: @monkeyintern That's not enough information, I recommend raising a new question with full details.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you want to see offers for a particular business, but you want to limit these according to certain profiles or skills?

We limit query results in the `WHERE` clause. If we want to look up data in another table, we use `IN` or `EXISTS`. For instance:

```
select *
from offer
where business_name = 'business-1'
and id_offer in
(
  select id_offer
  from ternary
  where id_profile = 1
    and id_skill = 2
);
```