# How to display posts from followers and logged-in user in news feed?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display posts from the users being followed and the logged in user using a single ***PHP*** ***MySql*** query.

I have three tables:

- `users` (user_id, username, ..)
- `posts` (post_id, content, added_by, ..)
- `Followers` (f_id, followed, followed_by)

I have variable

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_id']
```

```
$que = $db->prepare("SELECT posts.*, users.*, followers.follow, followers.followed_by FROM posts 
                    INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = posts.added_by_user_id
                    LEFT JOIN followers ON followers.follow = posts.added_by_user_id
                    WHERE (posts.added_by_user_id = $id OR followers.followed_by = $id) ORDER BY post_id DESC");
                $que->execute();
                $posts = $que->fetchAll();
```

But the query shows each post created by logged-in user twice.

Comment: DISTINCT could work for you. checkout here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068515/select-distinct-records-on-a-join

Comment: That is probably because of LEFT JOIN. Those 2 rows per post do they have different *followed by*?

Comment: I tries with distinct same result.

Comment: Only posts of the logged-in user shows twice, the posts of followers shows once

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following:

Add additional clause to you `LEFT JOIN followers` and it will do the trick i.e `LEFT JOIN followers ON ( followers.follow = posts.added_by_user_id AND followers.followed_by = $id )`  . Note the `AND`

```
$que = $db->prepare("SELECT posts.*, users.*, followers.follow, followers.followed_by FROM posts 
INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = posts.added_by_user_id
LEFT JOIN followers ON ( followers.follow = posts.added_by_user_id 
 AND followers.followed_by = $id ) 
   WHERE (posts.added_by_user_id = $id OR followers.followed_by = $id) 
GROUP BY( posts.post_id ) 
ORDER BY post_id DESC");
 $que->execute();
 $posts = $que->fetchAll();
```

Anotber way using your code, just add DISTINCT after SELECT. I.e `SELECT DISTINCT posts.*` .....

Another way is using sub query

```
$que = $db->prepare("SELECT posts.*, users.* FROM posts 
INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = posts.added_by_user_id 
WHERE posts.added_by_user_id= $id OR posts.added_by_user_id IN (SELECT follow FROM followers WHERE followed_by= $id) 
ORDER BY post_id DESC");
    $que->execute();
     $posts = $que->fetchAll();
```

You can also use the below. The key function is `GROUP BY`

```
$que = $db->prepare("SELECT posts.*, users.*, followers.follow, followers.followed_by FROM posts 
                    INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = posts.added_by_user_id
                    LEFT JOIN followers ON followers.follow = posts.added_by_user_id
                    WHERE (posts.added_by_user_id = $id OR followers.followed_by = $id) 
GROUP BY( posts.post_id ) 
ORDER BY post_id DESC");
 $que->execute();
 $posts = $que->fetchAll();
```

(I'm not too sure how efficient this is)