# SELECT DISTINCT WHILE JOINING TABLES

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL. I would like to ask some help.
How can I select only distinct values from a joined table?

```
    SELECT fc.Indv_Sys_Id, DISTINCT(fc.Dt_Sys_Id)
    FROM MiniHPDM..Fact_Claims AS fc
    INNER JOIN MiniHPDM..Dim_Date AS d on fc.Dt_Sys_Id = d.Dt_Sys_Id
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  You clearly do not understand that `DISTINCT` is not a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT DISTINCT values after a JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944350/select-distinct-values-after-a-join)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select distinct records on a join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068515/select-distinct-records-on-a-join)

Comment: Besides DISTINCT, you might see that some people also use `GROUP BY fc.Indv_Sys_Id, fc.Dt_Sys_Id` at the end to get uniqueness instead DISTINCT after SELECT. Pay attention that it is fine if you gonna use aggregate function in such cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want distinct values, then use `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fc.Indv_Sys_Id, fc.Dt_Sys_Id
FROM MiniHPDM..Fact_Claims fc INNER JOIN
     MiniHPDM..Dim_Date d 
     ON fc.Dt_Sys_Id = d.Dt_Sys_Id;
```

`DISTINCT` is not a function.  It is a keyword, used in this case with `SELECT`.

Given that the join should succeed, I imagine that this returns the same results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fc.Indv_Sys_Id, fc.Dt_Sys_Id
FROM MiniHPDM..Fact_Claims fc
WHERE fc.Dt_Sys_Id IS NOT NULL;
```